# C# Timer for MultiThreading that can ignore ticks

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, timer, threadpool

Regarding C# multithreading and events;

I'm trying to set up a System.Threading.Timer that triggers an AutoReset event.  When the event is signalled, the code will perform a task that might take longer than the next timer tick.

In C++, when timers set autoreset events, if the event is already set, effectively nothing happens, and you just miss that particular tick.  It works well, the thread can tick away setting an event that is already set, and there are no problems.

In C#, the setting of the event is queued up, either on multiple pool threads, or serially on the timer thread.  I have got the timer to callback to one thread but
I cannot for the life of me remember how I did that, I found it on StackOverflow, naturally.

It seems that the callback of the timer blocks until the AutoReset event is reset.
I cannot query the event to see if it is already set.

How can I get the system to ignore this?  If I am debugging one thread in the app and hold that thread up, the ticks back up and I get either thread exhaustion or database connection exhaustion, either of which kills the app off.

I have seen that I can use a System.Timers.Timer instead, but this requires a synchronizing object.  I know that I have to implement a synchronizing object, but I cannot figure it out.  I have found the specification of the interface, I seem to need a delegate function.  On numerous responses I see people suggesting you just create a dummy synchronization object, but it's that stage that I am stumbling on.

I feel like I am chasing my tail needlessly just to get the system to ignore timer ticks.  I have tried using bool flags to signal when threads are busy, but this seems like an ugly kludge.  An example ISynchronizeInvoke implementation would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give with this.

Comment: Tis a bit unclear.  A little bit of code would help...

Comment: Why the complex timer solution?  I would just have used a sleep() loop, Environment.TickCount at start and end of task and some modulo arithmetic to calculate the sleep interval required until the next run.  Do you really need a complex timer/event design that can, and does, go wrong?

Comment: @MartinJames: Thread.Sleep + ThreadPool = unreponsive app. A similar style can be acheived nicely in an async method that has `await Task.Delay(xxx)` in the loop.

Comment: What type of message loop do you have for your app?  You'd generally need to have one to create an implementation of `ISynchronizeInvoke`, and on top of *that*, I don't see how it solves the problem that you're asking to have solved.  It would still enqueue all of the tick events, which isn't what you want.

Comment: @spender - oh, I would not use a threadpool thread for an app-lifetime run:)  Task.Delay(xxx) sounds a better solution.

Comment: `AutoResetEvent.Set` does not block if the event is already set. You need to look somewhere else for the cause of your problem.

Comment: @MartinJames - I have a process that is designed to run every n milliseconds.  It's on it's own thread.  The solution works very well in C++, is not complex, and is reliable - I'm just looking for the c# analogue, and it's very nearly there, but not quite.

Comment: @Servy - no message loop at all, this is ASP.Net C#, but the ASP.Net aspect is not relevant.

Comment: @SteveHibbert It's *highly* relevant.  It dramatically impacts how you would go about properly marshaling a call to the correct context.  On top of that, if this is ASP, the solution may very well be, "don't use a timer at all."  There are better tools for solving this problem in such an environment.

Comment: @JimMischel - Good point, I may have a different issue, I will microcosm the situation and see if I can replicate.

Comment: @Servy - OK, what I have is a database, with a queue table.  ASP.Net pool threads load the queue table and go back to serving pages.  Custom thread consumes the queue when one of the loading thread signals it's event.

Comment: As @JimMischel says, Set does not block.  The problem comes in only during debugging.  If I interrupt the app with a debug point, all threads seem to suspend, but the timer ticks on.  When the app resumes, the backed up ticks spool through instantly, and this is what is killing the app.  Heisenberg strikes again.  Thanks to all for the assistance, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing can't happen. `AutoResetEvent.Set` does not block if the event is already set, as this code clearly shows:

```
    private System.Threading.Timer _myTimer;
    private AutoResetEvent _myEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private void DoIt()
    {
        _myTimer = new Timer(MyTimerCallback, null, 1000, 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter when done");
        Console.ReadLine();
        _myTimer.Dispose();
    }

    private void MyTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        _myEvent.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("tick");
    }
```

If you run that, it will output "tick" once per second until you press Enter.

That said, the problem of skipping ticks is easily handled by making a one-shot timer and re-enabling it after every tick. Like this:

```
private void DoIt()
{
    // Timeout.Infinite makes it a one-shot timer
    _myTimer = new Timer(MyTimerCallback, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    // other code
}

private void MyTimerCallback(object state)
{
    // do whatever processing is necessary
    // and then restart the timer
    _myTimer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

This way, the timer can't tick while a previous tick is still processing.

Comment: Note this does have difference semantics.  If the timer is set to run every second, and you have a handler that takes 500 ms, your code will essentially tick every 1.5 seconds, instead of ticking every second.  If the handler takes 1.5 seconds your code would tick every 2.5 seconds, rather than ticking every 2 seconds.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, that's true. I should have noted that. The semantics is "tick one second after the previous timer tick has finished processing."

Comment: Yes, different semantics, not a regular period.  Thanks for the reply, I will take a look at this tomorrow, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore ticks when a previous tick handler is still running you can trivally handle this through an `isRunning` field:

```
private volatile int isRunning = 0;

public void Tick()
{
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref isRunning, 1) == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            isRunning = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but isn't it irksome that the `Interlocked` methods don't do boolean?

Comment: @spender Yeah.  Really hope they add those overloads at some point.